# Set notation, what does it mean

Tags: notation

Can sonbody explain to me what does set notation of

$$
C_NM\\
$$

means.

The C in given notation is not letter C, it is some kind of very narrow C. I Could not find the alternative, to write.

Thanks

Comment: Complement of $M$ with respect to $N$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29  and http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/e/7/fe75ee3c3e1f30113d216dacfd04379c.png

Comment: You may enjoy finding the symbol at http://detexify.kirelabs.org .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean $\complement_N M$, which I first saw in Bourbaki.

$\complement_N M$ is the complement of $M$ with respect to $N$, also known as $N \setminus M$.

$\complement_N M$  is written as `\complement_N M` in $\TeX$.